# MSBuild cannot find reference when executed through TFS build service

Tags: reference, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

I have a solution with reference to Telerik assemblies. The referenced version has been installed on the build server. The issue is that the continuous integration build always succeeded until I upgraded the Telerik assemblies in the solution and on my build server. The build now fails giving the classical:

> Could not resolve this reference.

I checked my solution and everything is set to reference the specific version. The most suprising is that if I open the solution locally on the build server, everything will build without a problem... so that means the Telerik assemblies have been published somehow, but for an unknown reason, when MSBuild is called to compile the solution throught the build service, it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Get a detailed msbuild log of both builds and compare. It will tell you where it got the referenced assemblies from (when it succeeded) and where it tried (when it failed).

Comment: Yes, I would do what Alexey is saying below. Had similar problem few days ago and deleting all the references and creating them again was the solution.

Comment: Recreating all reference binding one by one did not solve the error. Almost a day has been spent on this issue so Telerik upgrade will probably wait for less tense period. Rolled back to previous version and everything went back in order.
I had a look at MSBuild logs and build server simply does not look int the right folders for some unknown reasons. Maybe the problems originates in the new Telerik package deployment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating to the Q3 release.

To solve this, I built the solution with Logging Verbosity set to Diagnostic, and found that MSBuild never bothered to look in the Telerik folder.

So to include that folder in the build, we simply added it by adding a MSBuild argument: 
/p:ReferencePath="C:\Program Files\Telerik\RadControls for WPF Q3 2012\Binaries\WPF40"

It's perhaps not the best, and needs to be updated everytime you update RadControls, but it works.

We run the build server on a x86 installation, so Telerik is located under C:\Program Files, but if you run on a x64, it's under C:\Program Files(x86), so if you run several build servers on both x64 and x86 installations, you must specify both path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove-then-add reference to updated dlls - you can then see in proj file if there any differences with referenced assembly.

Enable verbose\diag mode for msbuild (/v:diag command line key) and check build logs. Diag mode have very detailed output about referenced library search process.

Comment: I removed all references to Telerik and then remade them one by one but I still have the same error on build. Fixing and tracking down the error already took almost a day so we decided to rollback to previous version and it work fine again...
Also build service search process was looking in hundreds of folder without finding anything when build through Visual Studio did fine.

Comment: From visual studio log you can figure where exactly proper dll could be found. Then ensure that TFS searching that dir. Check <HintPath on reference in proj file and <ReferencePath in your proj.user file (I suspect latter could be the case - VS will use that file, but TFS should not).

Answer (score 0):

I normally find it's better to copy the referenced assemblies into the solution and reference them from there.  Then the build server and other developers don't need to worry about installing that specific version and you can support multiple projects running different versions of the component.

Comment: I only do that for assemblies that are not easily or not redistruable at all. I am not a big fan of loading the Source Control database with lot of dlls because some projects have lots of references and getting a project sources that has 50MB of assemblies can be painfull, especially if you are away from office with a bad connection. But I reckon it is a safe practice indeed.

Comment: Or create a custom NuGet package with the DLLs and enable package restore mode.  That way there's no DLLs in source control, machines without the install will get it (and it'll be smaller than downloading it from Telerik) and machines can build projects that reference multiple different versions.