# TFS Build not finding a binary reference

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a binary reference in 1 of my projects, this reference is relative, and looks something like this:

```
<Reference Include="MyNameSpace.Etc">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\SomeProject\SomeFolder\SomeFile.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Building locally works perfectly. The problem is the build server has no idea where to locate this reference because the relative path makes no sense.

My question is:

How can I instruct the build server to locate binary references in a folder that I designate. I want to be able to create a folder on the build server and populate it with any DLLs that I need and then have the build process know exactly where to find the DLLs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild cannot find reference when executed through TFS build service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800778/msbuild-cannot-find-reference-when-executed-through-tfs-build-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some references only in your local dev machine. To make sure the build on build server works well, there is three way for this situation:

1. Copy the dll file with the same path in your dev machine to the
   build server (Not recommend, since you can't use the relative path )
2. Check in this dll in source control (also not recommend), this can use the relative path. However, you must make sure your dll in the local path which match the relative path, for your example: the dll file must under `..\..\SomeProject\SomeFolder\SomeFile.dll`
3. Create a custom NuGet package with the DLLs, it will download the dll from NuGet sever on your build server. (Recommend)